# Will AIC and R-square rank models similarly if the number of variables is equal?

Tags: regression, aic

This is a fairly basic question: If a number of regression models are being evaluated for fit to a dataset, and each model has 3 variables, will AIC and R-square rank the models similarly? I'm assuming the answer is yes, because the penalty aspect of AIC for added variables would be a non-issue. But, I'm unclear if this would always be the case.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Since $R^2=1-SSE_{Error}/SSE_{Total}$:

$R^2 \uparrow \implies (\bf{Y}-\bf{X \beta})'(\bf{Y}-\bf{X \beta}) \downarrow$

The log-likelihood for a given model, assuming Gaussian errors is (omitting constants):
$-\frac{n}{2}\ln{\hat{\sigma}^2}+{\frac{1}{2\hat{\sigma}^2}(Y-X\beta)'(Y-X\beta)}$

But since $\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{(\bf{Y}-\bf{X \beta})'(\bf{Y}-\bf{X \beta})}{n}$, the log-likelihood reduces to:

$-\frac{1}{2} (\bf{Y}-\bf{X \beta})'(\bf{Y}-\bf{X \beta})$

So the log-likelihood increases as $(\bf{Y}-\bf{X \beta})'(\bf{Y}-\bf{X \beta}) \downarrow$, i.e. AIC decreases.

To summarize, in the normal case, for an equal number of predictors, yes, the two are equivalent. In words, the model that explains the most variability ($R^2$) should correspond to the model that fits best (has highest likelihood, or lower AIC).

I haven't checked, but I would imagine you could choose a distribution other than Gaussian for the errors that would lead you to a counter example.

Comment: Thanks for this illustration! It's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem, if you're satisfied with the answer, would you mind accepting it? Thanks.